# Show tooltip for elements in a string variable with ngx-bootstrap

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I would like to use `TooltipModule(ngx-bootstrap)` to show tooltip for buttons in a variable :

typescript:

```
public htmlContent=`<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" tooltip="First Tooltip">First Buttons</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" tooltip="Second Tooltip">Second Buttons</button> `;
```

html:

```
<div class="mt-5">
     <div [innerHTML]="this.htmlContent |safeHtml"></div>
</div>
```

**It does not work .**

Later , I will get the htmlContent form an API.

If I put the buttons in the html directly It works perfectly

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
        tooltip="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">Simple demo
</button>
```

**[Stackblitz Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vfh8nu)**

Comment: Will you get the tooltip content from the API or the whole HTML Markup from the API?

Comment: @SiddAjmera - I will have both of condition